# jquery.fileDownload: inform user of progress

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, http, jquery-plugins

I'm using John Culviner's (great) jquery.fileDownload plugin. It has callbacks for when the download has completed, but my file takes about 30 seconds to generate (lots of back end processing).

I want to inform the user of the current progress.

As a prototype, I am trying this:

1) (before the file download is initiated) - repeatedly poll a url every second ($.get(...)). It returns the % complete and updates a div on the page (0% at this point).

2) Initiate the fileDownload script (at this point, the server-side variables that 1) is checking start to get updated e.g. 2% complete.... 10% complete.... etc etc

3) Ideally, while the file is being built, my ajax calls in 1) are still simultaneously polling (and updating the div) so that the user starts to see some progress.

4) Download completes. I can hide the 'progress div' at this point since it will show 100%.

NB the progress div will be replaced with a progress bar eventually of course.

The trouble is, as soon as the fileDownload starts, the ajax calls in 1) start queuing up and are not actually executed until after 4)!

I think the fileDownload plugin uses an iframe which I wouldn't have thought would block the ajax calls in my main page, but it seems to.

Hope that makes sense. Grateful for any advice on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem with an ASP.NET MVC web application.
In my case, the problem was related to the server, as no two requests using the same session could be run concurrently. The session is not thread-safe in ASP.NET.

The solution for MVC projects is to decorate the controller with the `[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` attribute.
To share variables between two actions, employ the thread-safe `Cache` instead of the session.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem with this component and ASP.NET MVC5.  I decorated the controller containing my "progress" action with that SessionStateAttribute but it the call to my progress action still blocked until the file download finished.  Do I need to decorate both controllers with that same attribute?  That might be tough.